# Distributed Indexing using Zookeeper and Redis

Tags: caching, indexing, redis, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

Can we use zookeeper service to redirect a request coming from client to a particular Redis Node?
For example, I am having 10 Redis nodes(a cluster), where each cluster is containing some cached data.

So can I maintain indexing ranges for every node in the zookeeper, such that the zookeeper service knows which node has which range of indexes, and thus when a user asks for records within the range x to y it redirects to the Redis node holding that record range?

Comment: Did you check RediSearch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact this is 2-step indexing. Many db use 2-step sorted map

- Level-0 index (zookeeper in your case) contains Range mapping to Level-1 databases.
- Level-1 index (Redis in your case) contains actual data.

Popularly used by [cockroach db](https://youtu.be/1nQTX2sAWg8), [Google Big Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigtable#Design)

However there are other options as well like using consistent hashing which can avoid 2-level indexing like [dynamo db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_(storage_system)) if consistency is not a hard requirement.